# Random error: The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have been struggling with CoreData errors like "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store" in my production app for year.

In short.
I have the app with CoreData, use objective-c. The app is in AppStore. And FirebaseCrashlytics shows for some users "The model used to open the store is incompatible".

I've read many topics and I understand reason can be wrong migration from one model to another. Yes, I had 8 times changing model. And usually did lightweight migration.

But there are strange items :

1. This error occurs only for some users in random times.
2. If error occurs the app crashes. It's ok. But an user can run second or third time and error doesn't occur. The app works well. In some cases user must reload device to run the app without crash. Reloading helps 100% users.
3. On my own devices it happens only 1-2 time for 2 years. I not able to catch this case on Xcode.
4. It's not depend on model device or iOS version.
5. The app exists about 6 years. It started to happen 2-3 version (model) changing ago.

Code details:

I load "persistentContainer" in viewDidLoad (also tried load in AppDelegate the same situation):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        
        errorPersistentContainer= [[DataAccess sharedInstance]  getPersistentContainerWithResult]; 
        if ( errorPersistentContainer!=nil){ 
             
            [[FIRCrashlytics crashlytics] log:errorPersistentContainer.userInfo.description];
            [[FIRCrashlytics crashlytics] recordError:errorPersistentContainer]; 
            
            UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"error" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            
            [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"Ок" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                 
                //try second time!!
                errorPersistentContainer= [[DataAccess sharedInstance] getPersistentContainerWithResult_SecondTime]; 
                if (errorPersistentContainer!=nil){ //error again 
                    [self showDataAccessError];
                } else {//Everything is OK
                    [self initTabToday]; 
                }
                
            }]];
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }else { //Everything is OK
            [self initTabToday];
        }
        
    }
```

== DataAccess.m===

```
- (NSError*) getPersistentContainerWithResult_SecondTime {
    _persistentContainer = nil;
    return  [self getPersistentContainerWithResult];
}
//загружаем persistent Container
- (NSError*) getPersistentContainerWithResult { 
    __block NSError *errorResult=nil;
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (_persistentContainer == nil) {
            _persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"app_base"];
            
            NSURL *storeURL=[self getStoreURLWithFile]; 
   
            //migrate to app group (use embedded widget)
            if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:storeURL.path] == NO) {
                [self migrateToGroup:_persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator];
            } else {
                NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription=[[NSPersistentStoreDescription alloc] initWithURL:storeURL]; 
                _persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions = @[storeDescription];
 
                [self.persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *description, NSError *error) {
                    if (error != nil) {
                        errorResult=error;
                    } else {
                        [self.persistentContainer.viewContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
                    }
                    KSLog(@"initPersistentContainer done complete");
                }];
                KSLog(@"initPersistentContainer done after");
            }
        }
    }
 
    return errorResult;
}

-(void) migrateToGroup:(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*)coordinator {
    KSLog(@"migrateToGroup");
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *storeOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
    
    NSPersistentStore  *sourceStore        = nil;
    NSPersistentStore  *destinationStore   = nil;
    
    NSURL *oldStoreURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    oldStoreURL = [oldStoreURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"app_base.sqlite"];
    
    
    NSURL *storeURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:[self currentContainer]];
    storeURL = [storeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"app_base.sqlite"];
     
    // Add the source store
    if (![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:oldStoreURL options:storeOptions error:&error]){ 

    } else {
        sourceStore = [coordinator persistentStoreForURL:oldStoreURL];
        if (sourceStore != nil){
            // Perform the migration
            destinationStore = [coordinator migratePersistentStore:sourceStore toURL:storeURL options:storeOptions withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error];
            if (destinationStore == nil){
                // Handle the migration error
                NSLog(@"the migration error"); 
            } else {
                NSLog(@"ok - can remove old");
              
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

==== error from crashlytics ====

> NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100
> "The managed object model version used to open the persistent store
> is incompatible with the one that was used to create the persistent
> store." UserInfo={metadata={\n    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion =
> 1048;\n    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {\n        Friends =
> {length = 32, bytes = 0xa4233393 c2464286 0847efb8 92c58968 ...
> 49acb261 34ea84a8 };\n        Goal = {length = 32, bytes = 0x01145946
> 55708ff8 62354bd8 96312a81 ... 0f993736 d465c5c8 };\n
> KSSettings = {length = 32, bytes = 0x4a4ff768 95d9d482 5442f0b4
> 3c3f4932 ... 5e5683fe 0f9e37f1 };\n        List = {length = 32, bytes
> = 0x685a284a 56b681ab 8c90d929 1db22048 ... 52604c30 a373f09a };\n        Note = {length = 32, bytes = 0xd5c0a494 8359f711 626842c2 d21b88de ...
> 661e0c0c 50dc480f };\n        Shared = {length = 32, bytes =
> 0xbda79a1a 80065c47 9b964696 59f09f43 ... ec6601e2 a695220c };\n
> Stat = {length = 32, bytes = 0xce86d983 d05f4f7a ec4680f0 4fab7818 ...
> dfe3310b 5df27156 };\n        Tags = {length = 32, bytes = 0x06919599
> e01fb1bf ae276bc5 490a754a ... 1ad63318 e9b19428 };\n
> "Tags_Tasks" = {length = 32, bytes = 0x11b2b407 f472c1c7 460764df
> 53249c6b ... 27fb84fd c0787398 };\n        Task = {length = 32, bytes
> = 0x3c77d29d d0eb7338 55da69b9 b1c55118 ... c66d3888 1075e598 };\n    };\n    NSStoreModelVersionHashesDigest =
> "qWrsu1ZGw2BcEQ1cgxtdpioZxPlTVJb4Prz7iDU/BStANEdQh1u8clXpu1mbIeUx1ri3Unwl4+z7r/KjfRN/nw==";\n
> NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;\n
> NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (\n        ""\n    );\n
> NSStoreType = SQLite;\n    NSStoreUUID =
> "8D0217C5-992C-4B08-B11E-30ED01F5A089";\n    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel"
> = 2;\n}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}";
> reason = "Failed to open the store";

== In some previous version there was error

> "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (schema
> mismatch or migration failure). It cannot perform a save operation."

I will be very grateful for any ideas and solutions.
How can I solve problem with Core data model or may be my loading code is wrong?
Is it possible to find out what the difference in The model used to open the store between model used to create the store?